# Adding padding to an element with compass

Tags: susy-compass, compass-sass

i actually leaning compass and susy.So i found mixins for leader and trailer that add margin to my

element.
Actually i would to add padding to the same element, does exist a mixin for that or do i add it manually in css ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`padding-leader` and `padding-trailer` are the padding versions of `leader` and `trailer`. You can also use `rhythm-margins($leader, $trailer)` or `rhythm-padding($leader, $trailer)` to give both values at once.

That is all part of Compass, and not related to Susy.

Comment: ok,understanding what you say, but actually i need to add left or right padding and leader or trailer add top or bottom padding..

Comment: If you want to add padding to grid elements (anything using `span-columns`), then you have to set global `border-box` sizing, as described [in this article](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/). If you don't want to use `border-box` sizing, you have to apply your padding to non-grid elements. If you want to set padding in column-units, use the `prefix`, `suffix`, and `pad` mixins, as [described in the docs](http://susy.oddbird.net/guides/reference/#ref-helper-padding).